How can I restore the default functionality of q for macro recording in Neovim?
i have an issue with recording macros in Neovim. When I press qa to start recording a macro, it does not work. Here are the details of what I have tried:
Steps Taken:
Verified that q is mapped correctly by running :verbose nmap q, which returned:
n  q           * q
Last set from Lua (run Nvim with -V1 for more details)

This indicates that q is mapped to itself and should work.
Checked for potential keybinding conflicts by running:
:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_get_keymap('n')))

I reviewed the output in :messages and found no conflicts or additional mappings for q.
Tested in a clean Neovim session using:
nvim -u NONE

In this clean session, qa works as expected, allowing me to record and play back macros.
Attempted to remap q to its original behavior explicitly in my init.lua with:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'q', 'q', { noremap = true, silent = true })

However, this did not resolve the issue.
Checked my plugins and configuration for potential conflicts. I suspect that Lazy.nvim might be causing the problem, as it uses q in some of its mappings. However, I couldn’t pinpoint the exact cause.
Observations:
Running Neovim with no configuration (nvim -u NONE) resolves the issue, suggesting the problem lies within my configuration or plugins.
I’ve tried other registers (q1, qa, etc.), but they all fail with an
 error: E354: Invalid register name.

How can I restore the default functionality of q for macro recording in Neovim? Any insights into what might be causing this conflict or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Bisect your plugins, report an issue with the plugin that maps q.
